# Laravel 5.4 custom join (raw sql) mapped to an Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

Can somebody tell me how i can map the result of a Join made with RAW SQL or the Query Builder to an Eloquent Model ?

Teams has many Users who has Many Students who has many Projects

I'm doing a join to get all the projects of a team through the sub relations

Example :

```
$projects = Project::join('students', 'students.id', '=', 'projects.student_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'students.user_id')
            ->join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'users.team_id')
            ->select('projects.*', 'students.*', 'users.*', 'teams.*')
            ->get();
```

Now, how can i get the result here to be mapped to a Collection of "Project" Model having the sub relations mapped their respective Model

- Student
- User
- Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use joins. Use Eloquent's eager loading instead.

Provided you have relations defined correctly in your models, the following should do the trick:

```
$projects = Project::with('student.user.team')->get();
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $student = $project->student; //Student model
    $user = $student->user;  // User model
    $team = $user->team;  // Team model
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to fetch projects for given team do the following:

```
$projects = Project::with('student.user.team')->whereHas('student.user.team', function($query) use ($teamId) {
  $query->whereId($teamId);
})->get();
```

Comment: but i need to specify the team, there's the problem, in your example i can't, and if i want to do filtering and stuff how would i do that ?

Comment: and the hasmany through seems a good answer but it onlu allows one intermediate table, here i have two intermediate

Comment: and here i d'ont need to query the team i just need projects related to the team

Comment: seems a good way here, can you explain then why they have a hasManyThroug whereas your solution could just fit the case ? i wonder

Comment: plus second question, in some cases i would still need to do joins for very complexe relationships, how could i map it to a Model if that were the case ?

Comment: You can define hasManyThrough relation if you don't care about the models in the middle, but only about the end of the relation. Regarding your second question - Eloquent doesn't offer a way to map additional columns into multiple models. However it's usually not needed to use joins - have a look at whereHas method that lets you easily filter on related models without having to define a join explicitly.

Comment: well when i need outer joins "with" and "whereHas" doesn't match the need

Comment: Then use the join to filter results and with() to load related models. You won't get them from the joined columns with eloquent.

Comment: mmmmh this will give some really poor query perf, sometimes i regret laravel doesn't have a more complexe but powerful orm like symfony lol
thanks  anyway